# PWA dose not working or shown install app in browser menu

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps

I have made `serves-worker.js` and `Mainfest.json` and the other steps...

my [application](https://mohammed-zaky.github.io/pomodoro/)

and i check the performance and seo of my application.

the application is responsive

the application on GitHub

I follow all steps in this video on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/sFsRylCQblw)

Comment: This file seems to be missing? https://mohammed-zaky.github.io/service-worker.js

Comment: Also, the Chrome Lighthouse tool will help you with any issues that may prevent your website from being a valid/Installable PWA